# Isolating a variable

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have the following equation: $3y^2 + 2y - 2x^2 + 16x - 50 = 0$

I need to isolate y. But I have no idea how to tackle this. I keep getting stuck on trying to get rid of the $y^2$ term in order to have just $y$. I suppose there is some trick to solve this, but I have no idea what to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how to complete the square?

For example:

$$-2x^2+16x=-2(x^2-8)=-2(x-4)^2+32$$

Now do the same thing for $y$.

Comment: I probably learned this in high school, but I can't remember, haha. I looked up a reminder about this and I got it solved now!

Answer (score 0):

Treat this as a quadratic equation in $y$.

$$\color{red}{3}y^2 + \color{red}{2}y + \color{red}{- 2x^2 + 16x - 50} = 0$$

The three coefficients of this quadratic equation are shown in red. Now use the quadratic formula, completing the square, or other method to solve this equation. You will end up with $y=$ rather than the usual $x=$, but the same methods still work.

Comment: Using the quadratic formula to solve this is a very nice solution as well indeed! Thanks for the insight.